# Regex for matching alphanumeric within a String containing URLs

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

Given a few scenarios, how can I match and extract alphanumeric characters (and symbols) within a String containing URLs? I'm currently using Google Apps Script for retrieving a plain body text of a hyperlinked text from a Gmail thread message, and I'd basically like to match and extract the title out of some Strings as follows:

```
var scenario1 = "Testing: Stack Overflow Title 123? https://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

... in which I'd like to only output: `"Testing: Stack Overflow Title 123?"`

Here's another scenario:

```
var scenario2 = "https://www.stackoverflow.com Testing: Stack Overflow Title 123? https://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

... again, in which I'd like to only output: `"Testing: Stack Overflow Title 123?"`

I've tried the following for initially testing to see if the String first contains a URL (in which I confirmed that the regex for matching URLs works and outputs: `https://www.stackoverflow.com`), and then tests to see if a title exists to eventually extract it, but to no avail:

```
var scenario1 = "Testing: Stack Overflow Title 123? https://www.stackoverflow.com";
var scenario2 = "https://www.stackoverflow.com Testing: Stack Overflow Title 123? https://www.stackoverflow.com";
var urlRegex = /(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/;
var titleRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_:?']*$/;
var containsUrl = urlRegex.test(element);
if (containsUrl) {
    var containsTitle = titleRegex.test(scenario1);
    if (containsTitle) { // No match, and doesn't run
      var title = titleRegex.exec(element)[0];
      Logger.log("title: " + title);
    }
}
```

**Basically, I'd like a Regex pattern that matches EVERYTHING but URLs, if possible**

Comment: Can there be multiple non-URL substrings? (in which case, would you want an array of those substrings?)

Comment: Will all URL's begin with protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can capture any sequential text excluding what looks like a URL using this regex,

```
(?:^|\s+)((?:(?!:\/\/).)*)(?=\s|$)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?:^|\s)` - Matches either start of line or one or more whitespaces
- `((?:(?!:\/\/).)*)` - Matches any text except the one that contains `://` literally identifying it as a URL
- `(?=\s|$)` - Positive lookahead to ensure it is followed by a whitespace or end of line

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xfgjtp/1)**

This matches and captures any sequential text except URLs. Hope this works for you.

Here is a Javascript demo.

```js
var arr = ['Testing1: Stack Overflow Title 123? https://www.stackoverflow.com','https://www.stackoverflow.com    Testing2: Stack Overflow Title xyz? https://www.stackoverflow.com Hello this is simple text ftp://www.downloads.com/']

for (s of arr) {
 var reg = /(?:^|\s+)((?:(?!:\/\/).)*)(?=\s|$)/g;
 match = reg.exec(s);
 while (match != null) {
  console.log(match[1])
  match = reg.exec(s);
 }
}
```

Also, as I can see you want to limit the characters in your matching title, you can use your character set `[a-zA-Z0-9_:?' ]` (added space in your character set to allow capturing spaces as well) instead of `.` in my regex and use following regex to be more precise to avoid capturing title having unintended characters,

```
(?:^|\s+)((?:(?!:\/\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_:?' ])*)(?=\s|$)
```

**[Demo with your title character set](https://regex101.com/r/xfgjtp/2)**

Comment: This matches the leading whitespaces too, though, which probably isn't desirable.

Comment: Group1 captures the text that doesn't contain whitespaces.

Comment: I could have used positive look behind for whole matches to not contain any extra spaces, but lots of old tools/browsers don't support EcmaScript2018 and hence they all won't work so had to use grouping capture. And the group doesn't contain any extra leading/trailing white spaces as can be seen in my demo which should work for OP.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi +1 perfect

Answer (score 1):

One possibility could be to match until you encounter the first url using either a group or a positive lookahead.

Using a positive lookahead that might look like:

```
\bTesting: .*?(?=\s*(?:https?|ftps?):\/\/)
```

```js
const regexLookahead = /\bTesting: .*?(?=\s*(?:https?|ftps?):\/\/)/;
[
  "Testing: Stack Overflow Title 123? https://www.stackoverflow.com",
  "https://www.stackoverflow.com Testing: Stack Overflow Title 123? https://www.stackoverflow.com"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(regexLookahead)[0]));
```

Using a capturing group where your value would be in the first capturing group:

```
(\bTesting: .*?)\s*(?:https?|ftps?):\/\/
```

```js
const regexGroup = /(\bTesting: .*?)\s*(?:https?|ftps?):\/\//;
[
  "Testing: Stack Overflow Title 123? https://www.stackoverflow.com",
  "https://www.stackoverflow.com Testing: Stack Overflow Title 123? https://www.stackoverflow.com"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(regexGroup)[1]));
```

If you want to keep all except the urls, you could match them and replace with an empty string:

```
\s*(?:https?|ftps?):\/\/\S+
```

```js
[
  "Testing: Stack Overflow Title 123? https://www.stackoverflow.com",
  "https://www.stackoverflow.com Testing: Stack Overflow Title 123? https://www.stackoverflow.com",
  "https://www.stackoverflow.com test https://www.stackoverflow.com test https://www.stackoverflow.com test",
  "https://www.stackoverflow.com test",
  "test https://www.stackoverflow.com"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(/\s*(?:https?|ftps?):\/\/\S+/g, '').trim()));
```

Comment: This does depend on the non-URL substrings starting at a word boundary, though, and unfortunately lookbehind (for a space, or for `^`) isn't sufficiently widely supported yet as you probably know, not sure how I'd fix it

Comment: @CertainPerformance I see that you mean, I have added a replacing variant as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()` space characters and `.filter()` resulting array to exclude elements which begin with the specified protocols or end with word then dot character then word and end of string

```js
const splitURL = s => s.split` `.filter(w => !/^\w+(?=:\/\/)|\w+\.\w+$/.test(w)).join` `;
 
var scenario1 = "Testing: Stack Overflow Title 123? https://www.stackoverflow.com";

var scenario2 = "https://www.stackoverflow.com Testing: Stack Overflow Title 123? https://www.stackoverflow.com";

console.log(splitURL(scenario1), splitURL(scenario2));
```

Comment: Another option is to `.replace()` the URL with empty string using `urlRegexp` `s.replace(/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/g, '')`